# React native inside Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to open react native pages inside a fragment in android. 
I followed the following link [React-native inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221447/react-native-inside-a-fragment)

I am able to open the react native page but the touchlisteners inside react pages are not working.

Can somebody can suggest some method how to do it as the react native loses its focus when added to a fragment.

Comment: The accepted answer in the link you posted solves most of the problem with using react native in fragments. What you are probably missing is that in one of the comments in that answer they ask you to add some code in onResume. Personally I have used that solution and had it working, try it and it should work.