# Does React Native Really Support Android Fragments?

Tags: android, react-native

This question is harder to answer than it appears.

- ReactFragmentActivity does exist in master branch of React Native, BUT
- There is an open issue to create a React Fragment see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/12199/commits/e5b68717f57c41f5f1e77c289bdb4f673bb242f1
  // This has not been approved yet, but the need was acknowledged.
- I have looked at dozens of React Native examples on github etc, and fragments are never shown. Prove me wrong please!
- It's apparently not impossible see: [React-native inside a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221447/react-native-inside-a-fragment) but this solution seems not to fully deal with touch events.

My impression is that React Native is primarily focused around controlling the root view of the whole activity for layouts. I think there is some caution being used in taking on fragments.  As a side note React itself (not React Native) seems to have its own concept of a fragment.  I am guessing even Yoga layout manager inside React Native flexible as it is does not want to deal with Android Fragments. Not an issue so much for new apps but for integrating React Native into existing apps this is real issue!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, perhaps you already found the solution, but it can be helpful for someone else. The solution, you provided is really has some issues with touch events when you use native android `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`. But the react-native has own `ReactFragmentActivity` and if your activity extends this activity, the touch events works well, but only in separated fragment. It does not work with ViewPager and others. Only if fragment uses in separated Activity, like this:

```
Fragment reactFragment = new MainReactFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, reactFragment, "reactFragment").commit();
```

**EDIT:**

After some trials and errors,I got it to correct work with ViewPager and TabLayout(but I think in other cases it will work as well).So, here is what I did. The ReactFragment looks like this:

```
public abstract class ReactFragment extends Fragment {

    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    // This method returns the name of our top-level component to show
    public abstract String getMainComponentName();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(context);
    }

    public void setmReactInstanceManager(ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager){
        this.mReactInstanceManager = mReactInstanceManager;
    }

    @Override
    public ReactRootView onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return mReactRootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(
                mReactInstanceManager,
                getMainComponentName(),
                null
        );
    }
}
```

Then implement our fragment:

```
public class MainReactFragment extends ReactFragment {

    @Override
    public String getMainComponentName() {
        return "reactProject";
    }
}
```

We need to extend our activity from ReactFragmentActivity and initialize ReactInstanceManager:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactFragmentActivity {

    TabLayout tabs;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuItemTabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabMainMenu);

        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();

        TabsAdapter adapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mReactInstanceManager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And, of course, TabAdapter:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, `enter code here`ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
        mReactInstanceManager = reactInstanceManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MainReactFragment reactFragment = new MainReactFragment();
        reactFragment.setmReactInstanceManager(mReactInstanceManager);
        return reactFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "react tab " + position;
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image],

[image],

[image],

[image]

Comment: Why you extend ReactFragmentActivity, it is needed only to start js app, but your start js app from fragments?

Comment: I wrote about it at the start of my answer. If activity extends ReactFragmentActivity, then touch events works well, otherwise, there is an issues to handle touch events

Comment: is this solution can use here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416807/how-can-i-open-a-specific-component-of-my-react-native-application-from-an-nativ

Comment: Can you add to a github?

Answer (score 1):

early 2021:
I have created also blog post about it: https://stefanmajiros.medium.com/integration-of-native-android-fragments-and-views-into-react-native-a4156621543b

In general, you just render placeholder in React Native (as native UI component), then you would need find the id of that placeholder in React Native, send the id to the native part, and execute command that will attach fragment to the view, similar to this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(placeholderId, yourfragment, "sometag")
.commit();
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm just trying to do something similar: run a small Android App inside a React Native CustomView (Native Component). I did use an Intent but then it opens in fullscreen. I need it to open inside of the Native Component. Any thoughts? ty

Comment: This tutorial is for integrating 3rd party SDKs (native Android Views / Fragments) if you need to render them as a small part of the single screen. 

Mostly, React Native apps are single-activity apps, so you if use Intent to launch Activity, you should make sure that you launch the one w/ React Native.

However, if you need to convert the RN app into multiple activity-app, you can check the approach mentioned in the DOCS here https://github.com/innovatrics/dot-react-native-sample.

+ there is a recently added tutorial here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-android-fragment

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you. 
So, what you did is similar to what I'm looking for. 
The difference is that I'm trying to load an Activity but, per your example looks likes I will need to convert the Activity in a Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The React Native 0.66 have new instructions about the use of Android Native Fragments, more details here:
[Display Android Native Activity into React Native View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562692/display-android-native-activity-into-react-native-view/69688158#69688158)