# How can I open a specific component of my React Native application from an Native Android Activity in Java?

Tags: android, react-native

**Alert** - This question is basically about an approach. So there wont be any working pen or code to share!

I was doing a POC where integrating an RN app into an Android App. I did successfully following this [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps). Here is the previews - [image: Page A - Android Page][image: Page B - RN App]. 
onclick of click to got to RN button,RN activity started and page B get loaded. Upto here all good. Now i am wondering where i can introduce a RN component into page A. for example the button on page A can be RN component ? or How can I open a specific component of my React Native application from an Native Android Activity in Java?
 guess I have to check the ReactActivity in react-native repo to see how the a bundle gets rendered to the root view. The only thing that changes in my case is that I don't want to render to root view.
Here is files [Link1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java) and [Link2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivityDelegate.java)
This Q is asked in RN gitbub page - [Link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21128) - and they redirected to SO.
So please share you suggestion or approach

Comment: did you figure out how to connect to specific RN component from Android activity?

Comment: I can share my personal repo link where i implemented this. it must be outdated. However you can refer it: https://github.com/aravishack/React-Native-Page-in-Android-App and https://github.com/aravishack/React-Native-Component-in-Androd-App @JohnBarton